# Display custom product option in onpage checkout

Tags: checkout, cart

i want display custom option product in onepage checkout page, what i need do? and what i need add.

Comment: what do you mean by custom option? what have you tried so far?

Comment: when i added custom option for product, i send product to cart, in cart i see custom options, but when i try make process checkout, custom options - not visible, why?

Comment: where? on the review step? You should see them like in the cart there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked post by me on stackoverflow.com contains detailed information how to add item options dynammically.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266

Unfortunately it is a bit long to duplicate all the information here.
Hopefully it will give you what you need.